# Taking multiple shots in Nikon HDR mode

Tags: nikon, hdr

I understand that the HDR mode in Nikon works by taking 2 pictures (one overexposed, one underexposed and then merging (correct term?) together.

But what if the scene has a variety of objects and each has a different contrast...requiring to shoot maybe upto 5 - 7 images instead of just 2.
In this case, does the camera allow to shoot 5 - 7 images in HDR or do i need to manually combine the images later in photomatix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean the HDR mode that the D5100 has.  Possible one or two other models.  That only merges two shots internally into a JPG.  There is no way to take additional shots.  If you need more control, you'd need to manually shoot however many shots you need, use RAW and post-process.

If you use Matrix metering, you can select the EV difference between the two exposures, from 1-3 EV

> HDR is most effective when using Matrix metering, because the user is
>   given the choice of choosing the difference in exposure value between
>   the two shots from Auto, 1 EV, 2 EV or 3 EV. The camera automatically
>   uses a 2 EV difference in exposure value when set to Center-Weighted
>   or Spot metering.

http://www.nikonusa.com/en/Learn-And-Explore/Article/gltv4qwv/in-camera-hdr.html

Comment: Thanks, the 2 shots that it will take...would it randomly select 2 objects in the screen and choose the overexposure/underexposure settings?

Comment: If you use spot metering, I suppose it would take a +/- difference of that exposure value.  If you use matrix metering, it would compute a balanced exposure value for the whole scene, then do the two shots again +/- from that calculated exposure

Comment: And the metering is quite complex, who knows exactly what goes on in there.  It can detect backlit situations, recognize faces and adjust exposure accordingly.  But I don't think in any situation it takes two objects from a scene and calculates separate exposure values.  It first determines what exposure it would use for non HDR, based on the overall scene, then just does a +/- exposure compensation